# How this method gets the right diagonal from a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

Im practicing coding, right now Im practicing array-manipulation, and I found the following code for getting the left and right diagonal sum of a 2D Integer array. For the leftDiagonal, I understand, that basically the counter increments in both of the dimensions, therefore I get the ,[0][0],[1][1],[2][2] elements from the array which makes the left diagonal. Unfortunately, I dont really understand how the rightDiagonal is taken with the highlighted forloop. Why do I have to use `.get(arr.size()-(j+1))`? Is it because I if I dont add +1 to `int j` I would get `ArraysOutOfBondsException`?
Thank you for your kind help.

```
 public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
        int leftDiagonal = 0;
        int rightDiagonal = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < arr.size(); i++){
    leftDiagonal += arr.get(i).get(i);
        }
  -->      for(int j=0; j < arr.size(); j++){
    rightDiagonal += arr.get(j).get(arr.size()-(j+1)); 
        } <--
    int result = Math.abs(leftDiagonal -rightDiagonal);
    return result;
```

Comment: As you know, left diagonal is `[0][0],[1][1],[2][2]`. The right diagonal is `[0][2],[1][1],[2][0]` aka `[0][2-0],[1][2-1],[2][2-2]`, where `2` is `size - 1`. The formula `(size-1) - j` can also be written `size - j - 1` or `size - (j + 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because I if I dont add +1 to int j I would get ArraysOutOfBondsException?

Yes.

Arrays in Java are indexed from 0, so if you have an array of size `n`, then the last item is indexed with `n - 1`.